# Pass Persian string ( UTF-8 ) from laravel API to python file

Tags: python, php, laravel, utf-8

inside my `laravel-API` I have to call the `main.py` file and pass the **persian** string `UTF-8` to `main.py`

this is the `laravel-API`

```
$command = 'سلام چطوری؟'
$output = '';
exec("python ../../../python/main.py '$command'", $output);
dd($output);
```

this is the `main.py`

```
import sys

def main(text):
    return text

x = sys.argv[1]
print(x)
```

problem is when I pass something like this, it works correctly

> $command = 'hi how are you?'

```
//output
['hi how are you?']
```

but when I pass the Persian string like this, I got nothing in return

> $command = 'سلام چطوری؟'

```
#output
[]
```

Comment: I used python3 and It's work correctly for me. But I think you may have a error in exec state. If an error accord as the result of exec statement the output will be an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this code **before** calling `exec()` or `shell_exec()`

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
putenv("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8");
```

and when you want to pass your `$command` as a parameter use `utf8_encode()` and for output use `utf8_decode()`.

I have tested this with `shell_exec()` and it works fine for me.

summary:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
putenv("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8");
$command = utf8_encode($command);
$output = shell_exec("python path/to/your/.py/file '$command'");
$output = utf8_decode($output); // your final output
```